# Unbiased random walk : why is a random sample not calibrated

Tags: random-walk, calibration

To simplify, consider unbiased random walks with absorbing barriers at 0 and 100. A random walk starting at X has an expected probability to hit the barrier 100 of exactly X%.

However, it seems that if you take a finished random walk, and sample a point during the walk, with value Y, then the "probability" that is hits the barrier 100 is not Y%. I am aware that once a random walk is finished and you sampled a point, the probability is actually 1 or 0 because you know what values the rest of the samples will take.

To be precise, I did the following :

- Generate 1.000.000 random walks with random starting values from 1 to 99
- For each random walk, sample one point X and get the outcome (Y:hit the barrier 100 or Z:hit the barrier 0)
- For each value V from 1 to 99, get all the samples such that X==V and count how many times the outcome was Y (hit the barrier 100) and how many times the outcome was Z (hit the barrier 0)
- Check whether X is calibrated, i.e X == Y/(Y+Z). It clearly isn't

I did two experiments

1. If  instead of sampling a point for each random walk, I take the first point (and the associated outcome) then X is calibrated
2. If after I sample one point I truncate the rest of the random walk, generate a new one and get the associated outcome, then X is calibrated again

I don't understand why sampling existing random walks would yield different results than generating new random walks. The existing random walk is generated by the same process, it shouldn't matter whether it was run before or after the sampling

Comment: Did you intend to say $E[X]=\frac{Y}{Y+Z}$ rather than $\frac{Y}{Z}$?

Comment: Are you talking of a random walk over $\{0,1,\ldots,100\}$ or over $(0,100)$?

Comment: Henry : yes. Xi'an over the integers {0...100}

Comment: I do not see you accounting for **time**, which random walks are dependent on. Consider the difference between $E[X_{t}=x]$ and $E[X_{t+k}=x]$..